# Multiple Filters Mapbox (search and menu)

Tags: javascript, filter, mapbox

I have a mapbox map and I can filter based on a search box and menu buttons but only one of them will work at a time.

I  have a map with JSON data which includes types of services provided (menu filter) and counties where services are provided (searchbox filter) . I need it to work so that filtering on the menu does not cancel out the searchbox filter and vice versa. I have been trying to figure out how to combine the two with little success. I am also displaying results of the filters in a listing like  [here][1] Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you. Below is my code for the filters.

```
$('#search').keyup(search);
function search() {
    listings.innerHTML = '';

    // get the value of the search input field

    var searchString = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
   $('#search').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

   locations.setFilter(showState);

// here we're simply comparing the 'county' property of each marker
// to the search string, seeing whether the former contains the latter.

   function showState(feature) {
    return feature.properties.county
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(searchString) !== -1;
};
return false;
}

$('.menu-uiA a').on('click', function() {
    listings.innerHTML = '';

    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.

    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    locations.setFilter(function(f) {

    // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
    // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
    // a value set to true based on the filter name.

    return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
  });
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not introduce a uniform `SetFilterState` function which is triggered from either the `keyup` on #search or a `click` on your menu, which consolidates all conditions of the search criteria that you need to pass to `setFilter`?So there is only one place where the actual filter state is set.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example? I am relatively new to javascript.

Comment: any chance of this going into a jsfiddle so we can see more of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to combine the search and menu filters with the code below.

```
var searchString = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();                     
var filter = $('.menu-uiA a').data('filter');  

function combined_filter(f) {
    return ((f.properties.county
     .toLowerCase()
     .indexOf(searchString) !== -1) && ((filter === 'all') ?
true :f.properties[filter] === true))
};  

 $('#search').keyup('search', function() {
listings.innerHTML = '';
searchString = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();    

locations.setFilter(combined_filter);

return false;
});

 $('.menu-uiA a').on('click', function() {
listings.innerHTML = '';
filter = $(this).data('filter');
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

locations.setFilter(combined_filter);

return false;
});
```